# How to change installed keyboard via clicking edittext

Tags: android, keyboard

Changing installed keyboard via clicking edittext through device adminstation

Here the get list of keyboard installed name and package name. so need to change keyboard for different edittext.

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

List<InputMethodInfo> InputMethods = imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to change installed keyboard via clicking edittext through device adminstation

The device administration APIs do not allow you to change the user's chosen input method editor.

Comment: Ok. How to acheive this concept. For ex i have 3 edittext.  one editext i assumed one keyboard.

Comment: @RajasekaranT: Android SDK apps do not have the ability to change the user's chosen input method editor. While I cannot rule out the possibility that an app on a rooted device might be able to do this, I am not aware of a recipe for it, let alone one that could be applied on the fly as you are suggesting.

Comment: Ok. Any other possibilities, this is the requirement for client given

Comment: @RajasekaranT: You can download the source code to Android, change it to weaken security and allow Android SDK apps to forcibly change the user's chosen input method editor, compile and package that into a ROM mod, and install that on the client's device. Then, write your app to take advantage of the security hole that you introduced.

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to get current install keyboard Name.

Comment: @RajasekaranT: Off the cuff, I do not know how you would do that. Finding all the input method editors might be doable through `InputMethodManager`, or else from `PackageManager` with some work. You may wish to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question on that.